# Webkit.net - cannot find localized strings

Tags: .net, webkit.net

I've taken over a project that includes Webkit.net as it's internal browser. While it works fine for the most part, whenever there is an input element on a page, it displays it's text as "localized string not found".

There are localized string documents that exist in Webkit.resources\en.lsproj, but it does not appear to be picking them up.

I'd appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else has this issue, it turns out I was simply had not set a few files in the Webkit.resources folder to be copied to the output folder.